# Can there be context rich problems in Biology?

Tags: research-process, teaching, biology

[Context-rich problems](https://serc.carleton.edu/sp/library/context_rich/index.html) are short realistic scenarios giving students a plausible motivation for solving the problem.

As we search research literature, one can see lots of research in context rich problems done in physics and chemistry, but we don't see them in biology. Why is this?

Comment: Instead of pretending that you are giving them "real" problems, or instead of trying to look like it, why don't you give them really really real problems, like research problems, and let them try to solve it? The fact that none of them will be able to do so is not relevant.

Comment: @onurcanbektas, that is probably unrealistic and too frustrating for undergraduate education. Also it would be devilishly difficult to evaluate and assess.

Comment: Probably this is because physics and chemistry (along with math) are more often subjects where problems (especially equation-based ones) are often given without supporting context, so educators have put more work into studying now else to approach them.

Comment: Perhaps you can start with finding some application of biology in real life that is used to make decisions? I'm not from a biology background, and from my perspective, I cannot find any examples where my decision is heavily influenced by my knowledge in biology.

Comment: @Buffy Assigning research problems to undergraduates in a classroom setting is ubiquitous in the humanities.  It's not unrealistic in general.

Comment: I'm not familiar with biological pedagogy, but I don't believe the premise of the question.  I'm sure some biology faculty do this.

Comment: @Buffy Maybe for math, but not for Science subjects